# Explaination about this step in Varnish Documentation

Tags: apache, caching, varnish

Step: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html

These are my single steps:

1) pkill varnishd  **(done!)**

2) Edit the configuration for your web server and make it bind to port 8080 instead of 80"

What mean this step? I use Apache

3) default.vcl and change the port of the default backend to 8080 **(done!)**

4) varnishd -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 **(done!)**

Varnish doesn't work because i skip the 3th step. What i have to do there? Explain single steps...

PS: What's a simpler alternative to Varnish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that both Varnish and Apache is served from the same machine since you need to change ports. The standard www port is 80. You want Varnish to serve that port, and forward requests to Apache that would run on another port (8080).

I don't configure the ports of Apache often, but I think the following description should work. Edit the httpd.conf file (often found in "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf") and change the port setting from "Port 80" to "Port 8080", and restart apache. You may also have to change "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080" if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Debian here are the instructions:

1. Stop Varnish : `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`
2. Stop Apache  : `sudo /etc/init.d/varnish stop`
3. In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` change `Listen 80` into `Listen 8080`
4. Update all your virtual host to be on port 8080, in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*` change `<VirtualHost xxxxxxxxxxx:80>` to `<VirtualHost xxxxxxx*:8080>`
5. In `/etc/default/varnish` change the following code:

   DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
                -T localhost:6082 \
                -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
                -S /etc/varnish/secret \
                -s malloc,256m"

by the following

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :8080 \                     <======== THIS LINE
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

And in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` declare your backend with the following code:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

1. Start Apache : `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`
2. Start Varnish : `sudo /etc/init.d/varnish start`

Comment: Close, but Varnish needs to listen on port 80: `DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \ -T localhost:6082`...